# Cypress Cucumber ^ ParseError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress

Seem to be getting the following exception when trying to run my Tests within Chrome and Electron browser:

```
cypress-auto-framework\cypress\integration\Cucumber\EATest.feature:2
    Test the EA Features
         ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

My Feature File used to capture the requirements:

```
Feature: EaTestFeature
    Test the EA Features

    Scenario: Test the login feature
        Given I visit the EA site
        And I click on the login link
        And I login using credentials "admin" and "Password"
```

My Steps file used to map my feature file with actually actions:

```
import {Given, When, And, Then} from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps"
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

Given('/^I visit the EA site$/', () => {
    cy.visit('http://eaapp.somee.com/')
})

And('/^I click on the login link$/', () => {
    cy.contains('Login').click();
})

And('/^I login using credentials {string} and {string}$/', (userName, password) => {
    cy.get('#UserName').type(userName)
    cy.get('#Password').type(password)
    cy.get('.btn').click();
})
```

Plugins > index.js file:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

  module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
  }
}
```

Package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "cypress-auto-framework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.6.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^1.16.2",
    "cypress-dark": "^1.7.14",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also encountering same issue, have you found a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing regex steps and plain string type placeholders.
You have 2 possible options:

1. Write definition with regex: `And(/^I login using credentials "(.*?)" and "(.*?)"$/, ...`
2. Write definition as string with type placeholders: `And('I login using credentials {string} and {string}',...`

Comment: thank you for the comment but it seems that is not the area of the feature file which is affected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is that you  put your cucumber plugin in the wrong index.js file, it should be in plugins > index.js, not support > index.js

Comment: This could serve better as a comment if you wish this to be an answer then please elaborate more on the why's and how's

Comment: @Vitaliy F the cucumber plugin settings are added to: Plugins > index.js file, please see my previous example listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the cucumber constant outside of the config block

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
  }
}
```